# R Code gmapsdistance

Tags: r, indexoutofboundsexception, api-key

I have the following code used to find the travel time between two locations.  I am using vba to call the script which is why the command args shows up at the top but for testing purposes I am just setting the variables.  This was working until today (didn't change anything) and now I keep getting this error once i run the results line: Error in rowXML[[dur]] : subscript out of bounds.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this or what it means?

Code:

```
#install and load necessary packages
#install.packages("gmapsdistance")
#install.packages("devtools")

args<-commandArgs(trailingOnly=T)

library("gmapsdistance")
library("devtools")
devtools::install_github("rodazuero/gmapsdistance")

#input variables from excel
orig <- args[1]
dest <- args[2]
filePath <- args[3]
api_key <- args[4]

 orig <- "London"
 dest <- "Paris"
 filePath <- "C:/Users/gabby/Documents/SeniorYear/SeniorDesign/TravelTimes/Travel_Times.csv"
 api_key <- "############################"

set.api.key(api_key)

#calls google maps and finds the time
results = gmapsdistance(origin = c(orig, dest), destination = c(dest, orig), mode = "driving", traffic_model = "best_guess", 
                        key = api_key, combinations = "pairwise", shape = "wide")

#put results in a data frame
results2 <-  data.frame(results)

#rename the column headings
names(results2) <- c("Origin","Destination", "Time", "X1","X2","Distance","X3","X4","Status")

#delete repeated origin/destination columns
results2$X1 <- NULL
results2$X2 <- NULL
results2$X3 <- NULL
results2$X4 <- NULL

#convert seconds to minutes
results2$Time <- results2$Time/60

#convert meters to miles
results2$Distance <- results2$Distance*0.000621371

#add extra column and input the current date/time for documentation
results2[,"Date"] <- NA
results2[1,"Date"] <- format(Sys.time(), "%a %b %d %X %Y %Z")

#write results2 to a csv file and save it in my folder
write.csv(results2, file = filePath)
```

Comment: Check in the Google API console whether you've exceeded your quota for the day

Comment: The error will be coming from [this line](https://github.com/rodazuero/gmapsdistance/blob/831541fc8cd11e289f17daf4f23e332b3356f252/R/gmapsdistance.R#L258), which to me suggests the API call failed and therefore there was no `duration` value

Comment: You can also test your code on my [`googleway`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/googleway/index.html) package that also calls Google Maps API. If it fails on both packages, it suggests the issue is not in the R code

Comment: I am able to reproduce his problem

Comment: @Hack-R - I'm guessing Gabby is a 'her'

Comment: Thank you for the quick replies.  I checked my api and i have only used it 34 times today so i have not reached the limit.  Any ideas what else I could do to fix it?

Comment: I generated a new key but it is still giving the same error.  This is my first time using the keys so I am not sure what causes them to break or stop working.  I would appreciate any feedback.

Comment: In the API, when using `traffic_model`, you also need to specify a departure time

Comment: In the documentation it says that if you dont put anything for departure time then it defaults to the current time which is what i would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I obtained an API key, reproduced your problem, and then stepped through the underlying function's source code line by line.

The error is caused by the following:

```
data$Time[i] = as(rowXML[[dur]][1L]$value[1L]$text, 
                        "numeric")
```

because the object `dur` contains only the following:

> ```
> > dur
> [1] "duration"            "duration_in_traffic"
> ```

Thus `rowXML[[dur]]` throws the error. I'm not sure where to point the finger, but very often API's change faster than the packages built around them.

Nevertheless, you can still use the source code to get your result, as I did. It just takes a few more lines of code to clean up the results yourself:

```
xmlChildren(results$row[[1L]])
```

> ```
> $status
> <status>OK</status> 
>
> $duration
> <duration>
>   <value>20185</value>
>   <text>5 hours 36 mins</text>
> </duration> 
>
> $distance
> <distance>
>   <value>459271</value>
>   <text>459 km</text>
> </distance> 
>
> $duration_in_traffic
> <duration_in_traffic>
>   <value>20957</value>
>   <text>5 hours 49 mins</text>
> </duration_in_traffic> 
>
> attr(,"class")
> [1] "XMLInternalNodeList" "XMLNodeList"
> ```

Per your request in the comment, here's a bit more about what I did to get this.

First, take the arguments from the call to this function and create objects out of them (i.e. just run each argument as an individual command to create the objects). Next, load the `XML` and `Rcurl` libraries. Also, put your API key in an object called `key`.

After that you just take the source code of the function and run it line by line, skipping the part where the function call is defined. Along the way there are a small number of unused arguments which you can just create and set to `""`.

> ```
> #    function (origin, destination, combinations = "all", mode, key = #get.api.key(), 
> #              shape = "wide", avoid = "", departure = "now", dep_date = "", 
> #              dep_time = "", traffic_model = "best_guess", arrival = "", 
> #              arr_date = "", arr_time = "") # don't run this
> ```

```
  if (!(mode %in% c("driving", "walking", "bicycling", "transit"))) {
    stop("Mode of transportation not recognized. Mode should be one of ", 
         "'bicycling', 'transit', 'driving', 'walking' ")

  if (!(combinations %in% c("all", "pairwise"))) {
    stop("Combinations between origin and destination not recognized. Combinations should be one of ", 
         "'all', 'pairwise' ")
  }
  if (!(avoid %in% c("", "tolls", "highways", "ferries", "indoor"))) {
    stop("Avoid parameters not recognized. Avoid should be one of ", 
         "'tolls', 'highways', 'ferries', 'indoor' ")
  }
  if (!(traffic_model %in% c("best_guess", "pessimistic", "optimistic"))) {
    stop("Traffic model not recognized. Traffic model should be one of ", 
         "'best_guess', 'pessimistic', 'optimistic'")
  }
  seconds = "now"
  seconds_arrival = ""
  UTCtime = strptime("1970-01-01 00:00:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", 
                     tz = "GMT")
  min_secs = round(as.numeric(difftime(as.POSIXlt(Sys.time(), 
                                                  "GMT"), UTCtime, units = "secs")))
  if (dep_date != "" && dep_time != "") {
    depart = strptime(paste(dep_date, dep_time), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", 
                      tz = "GMT")
    seconds = round(as.numeric(difftime(depart, UTCtime, 
                                        units = "secs")))
  }
  if (departure != "now") {
    seconds = departure
  }
  if (departure != "now" && departure < min_secs) {
    stop("The departure time has to be some time in the future!")
  }
  if (dep_date != "" && dep_time == "") {
    stop("You should also specify a departure time in the format HH:MM:SS UTC")
  }
  if (dep_date == "" && dep_time != "") {
    stop("You should also specify a departure date in the format YYYY-MM-DD UTC")
  }
  if (dep_date != "" && dep_time != "" && seconds < min_secs) {
    stop("The departure time has to be some time in the future!")
  }
  if (arr_date != "" && arr_time != "") {
    arriv = strptime(paste(arr_date, arr_time), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", 
                     tz = "GMT")
    seconds_arrival = round(as.numeric(difftime(arriv, UTCtime, 
                                                units = "secs")))
  }
  if (arrival != "") {
    seconds_arrival = arrival
  }
  if (arrival != "" && arrival < min_secs) {
    stop("The arrival time has to be some time in the future!")
  }
  if (arr_date != "" && arr_time == "") {
    stop("You should also specify an arrival time in the format HH:MM:SS UTC")
  }
  if (arr_date == "" && arr_time != "") {
    stop("You should also specify an arrival date in the format YYYY-MM-DD UTC")
  }
  if (arr_date != "" && arr_time != "" && seconds_arrival < 
      min_secs) {
    stop("The arrival time has to be some time in the future!")
  }
  if ((dep_date != "" || dep_time != "" || departure != "now") && 
      (arr_date != "" || arr_time != "" || arrival != "")) {
    stop("Cannot input departure and arrival times. Only one can be used at a time. ")
  }
  if (combinations == "pairwise" && length(origin) != length(destination)) {
    stop("Size of origin and destination vectors must be the same when using the option: combinations == 'pairwise'")
  }
  if (combinations == "all") {
    data = expand.grid(or = origin, de = destination)
  }
  else if (combinations == "pairwise") {
    data = data.frame(or = origin, de = destination)
  }
  n = dim(data)
  n = n[1]
  data$Time = NA
  data$Distance = NA
  data$status = "OK"
  avoidmsg = ""
  if (avoid != "") {
    avoidmsg = paste0("&avoid=", avoid)
  }











  for (i in 1:1:n) {
    url = paste0("maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=", 
                 data$or[i], "&destinations=", data$de[i], "&mode=", 
                 mode, "&sensor=", "false", "&units=metric", "&departure_time=", 
                 seconds, "&traffic_model=", traffic_model, avoidmsg)
    if (!is.null(key)) {
      key = gsub(" ", "", key)
      url = paste0("https://", url, "&key=", key)
    }
    else {
      url = paste0("http://", url)
    }
    webpageXML = xmlParse(getURL(url))
    results = xmlChildren(xmlRoot(webpageXML))
    request.status = as(unlist(results$status[[1]]), "character")
    if (!is.null(results$error_message)) {
      stop(paste(c("Google API returned an error: ", xmlValue(results$error_message)), 
                 sep = ""))
    }
    if (request.status == "REQUEST_DENIED") {
      set.api.key(NULL)
      data$status[i] = "REQUEST_DENIED"
    }
    rowXML = xmlChildren(results$row[[1L]])
    Status = as(rowXML$status[1]$text, "character")
    if (Status == "ZERO_RESULTS") {
      data$status[i] = "ROUTE_NOT_FOUND"
    }
    if (Status == "NOT_FOUND") {
      data$status[i] = "PLACE_NOT_FOUND"
    }
    if (Status == "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT") {
      stop("You have exceeded your allocation of API requests for today.")
    }
    if (data$status[i] == "OK") {
      data$Distance[i] = as(rowXML$distance[1]$value[1]$text, 
                            "numeric")
      dur = grep("duration", names(rowXML), value = TRUE)
      data$Time[i] = as(rowXML[[dur]][1L]$value[1L]$text, 
                        "numeric")
    }
  }


  datadist = data[c("or", "de", "Distance")]
  datatime = data[c("or", "de", "Time")]
  datastat = data[c("or", "de", "status")]
  if (n > 1) {
    if (shape == "wide" && combinations == "all") {
      Distance = reshape(datadist, timevar = "de", idvar = c("or"), 
                         direction = "wide")
      Time = reshape(datatime, timevar = "de", idvar = c("or"), 
                     direction = "wide")
      Stat = reshape(datastat, timevar = "de", idvar = c("or"), 
                     direction = "wide")
    }
    else {
      Distance = datadist
      Time = datatime
      Stat = datastat
    }
  }
  else {
    Distance = data$Distance[i]
    Time = data$Time[i]
    Stat = data$status[i]
  }
  output = list(Time = Time, Distance = Distance, Status = Stat)
```

Comment: would you mind sharing the code that you added to make it work?

Comment: @GabbyPotvin Sure, no problem, just a second.

Comment: thank you! i apologize i am very new to this... where does that code go?

Comment: @GabbyPotvin I just updated the answer with more instructions and code. The part that contains your result is created mid-way through; you'll see it.

Comment: I don't quite see how `rowXML[[dur]]` throws the error, because the line above that is `grep`-ing for `duration`...?

Comment: @SymbolixAU It's because of the double brackets. With single brackets no error.

Comment: @Hack-R i finally got this to work. thanks again for the help! from the xmlChildren(results$row[[1L]]), do you know how i can extract just the number 20957 under duration_in_traffic?  eventually i need it output to csv.  i was trying some of the options on this website but couldn't get it to work.  http://www.omegahat.net/RSXML/shortIntro.pdf

Comment: @SymbolixAU i just saw you replied on my other post.  it is in reference to this issue.  any help would be appreciated.more info in the comment above.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not constrained to using `gmapsdistance`, my `googleway` package will give you the same results. The only difference is currently you have to specify the `departure_time`.

```
library(googleway)

orig <- "London"
dest <- "Paris"
api_key <- "your_api_key"

result <- google_distance(origin = c(orig, dest), destination = c(orig, dest), 
                         mode = "driving", 
                         traffic_model = "best_guess",
                         departure_time = Sys.time() + 60,
                         key = api_key)


result$rows$elements
# [[1]]
# distance.text distance.value   duration.text duration.value status
# 1           1 m              0           1 min              0     OK
# 2        459 km         459271 5 hours 36 mins          20185     OK
# 
# [[2]]
# distance.text distance.value   duration.text duration.value status
# 1        470 km         470366 5 hours 25 mins          19484     OK
# 2           1 m              0           1 min              0     OK
```

Comment: @GabbyPotvin no problem - not really the ideal time for your code to break, just before a demo :)

Comment: I know! frustrating! i went ahead and ran this but got the following error: Error in match.arg(traffic_model) : 'arg' should be one of

Comment: @GabbyPotvin ha - oh yeah, I fixed [that bug](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/issues/16) in the development version, so it's not yet on cran. If you want you can get it by going `library(devtools); install_github("SymbolixAU/googleway")` - And in the dev version I've also git it plotting interactive google maps